# Gnuplot multiplot y-axis scaling

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to be able to overlay a number of graphs using multiplot. I would like to enable auto-scaling to get the maximum resolution but I find that each dataset is independently scaled. Does anyone know how I might be able to scale all the graphs by the same amount so that they are all correct relative to each other ?

My data is being supplied via a pipe from an external system but here is a simple example. If I plot these two signals I would like the plot scale to be +/- 2.0 (from the cos) and then the sin to be scaled appropriately so that it is only half the height of the cos, rather than both the same height.

```
set multiplot
plot sin(x) with lines ls 1 linecolor rgb "blue"
plot 2*cos(x) with lines ls 1 linecolor rgb "red"
unset multiplot
```

Answer (score 1):

No, inside a multiplot you cannot automatically rescale a previous plot based on the data of the current plot. The data of a previous plot aren't available for later manipulations (zooming, replotting, rescaling etc). Run your minimal script and try to zoom in; you'll get only the zoomed last plot.

It could be done running the `stats` command for every data set to determine the maximum range.

```
max(x, y) = (x > y ? x : y)
min(x, y) = (x < y ? x : y)
do for [i=1:6] {
    stats '-' using 1 nooutput
    if (i == 1) {
        ymin = STATS_min
        ymax = sTATS_max
    } else {
        ymin = min(STATS_min, ymin)
        ymax = max(STATS_max, ymax)
    }
}
set yrange[ymin:ymax]
```

But since you are piping your data, you would need to send all data sets twice. Or you must determine the maximum range in your application and send a `set xrange[...]` command to gnuplot.

Comment: Hi Christoph, Thanks very much, as always, for your comments. I am sure you are correct but it does seem a great shame that this isn't a standard feature, like it is on other plotting packages. FYI, I'm not knocking Gnuplot because it is still by far the best :-). For now I'll pre-scale all the data. All the best, John